# Comparing CPU to QPU In terms of processing power

Tags: classical-computing, speedup, ibm-quantum-devices

The current processors are limited by the speed of the electrons but quantum processors take advantage of the properties of subatomic particles. But the question is how to compare the processing power of these two processors.

*How to compare the processing power of CPU and QPU to solve and calculate mathematical and cryptographical equations?*

Like an "Intel Core i9 CPU" vs "IBM Q 5 Tenerife QPU"?

Comment: the speed of the electron is not so much the issue, the speed of the electromagnetic wave that propagates in the CPU is limited to the speed of light.
Also, the CPU has a different (theoretical) model of computation. (QTM vs TM). Could you specify what you would like to quantify?

Comment: @Fleeep would you please explain "the speed of the electron is not so much the issue, the speed of the electromagnetic wave that propagates in the CPU is limited to the speed of light" a little bit simpler to me?